# For block.pls, how do you make the list needed for X

Tags: block, pls

For block.pls, how do you make the list needed for X. If I have to use gene expression data and metabolomics data versus type of cancer how would I set this up? Using data that is called typesofcancerdata

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: It will be useful if you can add more info